How to set a specific timeout for each API in the system?
For example:

I have the api/v1/list that I want to set a timeout of 1000ms for execution. If the execution time exceeds 1000ms, it will throw a TimeoutException.

Similarly, I have api/v1/detail and want to set a timeout of 3000ms for it. ........

Likewise, for each API, I want to set a different timeout. So how do I handle this issue?
Currently, I have written a custom Annotation that takes a value in milliseconds:
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TimeOut {
    long value() default 5000;
}



And a bean to catch and handle errors at that API:
@Aspect
@Component
public class TimeoutAspect {
    
    @Around("@annotation(timeoutAnnotation)")
    public Object applyTimeout(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, TimeOut timeoutAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        long timeout = timeoutAnnotation.value();
        return applyTimeout(joinPoint, timeout);
    }

    private Object applyTimeout(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, long timeout) throws Throwable {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Object> future = executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                return joinPoint.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
            }
        });

        try {
            return future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw new TimeoutException("Execution timed out after " + timeout + " milliseconds");
        } finally {
            future.cancel(true);
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}

But it seems like this approach causes my API to lose its Authentication and this becomes null: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().
Help me without using Transactional, Webflux and other 3rd library.
I tried to create Bean and point-cut for handling timeout each annotation and it seem to clear my Authentication
Thanks so much for any help!
